# How to use datasets correctly in windows

Tags: windows, pytorch, dataset

Recently I use torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder to process image(.tif) in windows, but my program terminated when I try to iterate the dataset without any exception.What confusing me is that the code could run in MacOS correctly.

dataloaders.py

```py
import torchvision.datasets as dset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
import os
map_list = ['test', 'train', 'valid']

root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'datasets'))

def get_datasets(root_path:str, split_type:str):
    path = os.path.join(root_path, split_type)
    data_transform = {
        'train': transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                     transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.467,0.467, 0.467],
                                                         std=[0.041, 0.041, 0.0414])
                                                          ]),
        'test': transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.467,0.467, 0.467],
                                                         std=[0.041, 0.041, 0.0414])
                                                         ]),
        'valid': transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.467,0.467, 0.467],
                                                         std=[0.041, 0.041, 0.0414])
                                                        ])   
    }
    dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root=path, transform=data_transform[split_type])
    return dataset

def get_dataloader(root_path:str=root_path, split_type:str='train', batch_size:int=32, 
                   shuffle:bool=True, num_workers:int=8):
    dataset = get_datasets(root_path, split_type)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=num_workers)
    return dataloader
```

Is there any problem in my dataloader?